# Removing blank line at end of string before writing to text file?

Tags: vb.net, string, text-files, newline

Been searching around for this for a couple hours, can't find anything which will do this correctly. When writing a string to a text file, a blank line is outputted at the end.

```
writeString = New StreamWriter(path, False)
writeString.WriteLine("Hello World")
writeString.Flush()
writeString.Close()
```

This will write the following to file:

```
Hello World
(Blank Line)
```

I've tried removing last character of string (both as regular string with `varString.Substring(0, varString.Length - 1)` and also as a list of string with `varList.RemoveAt(varList.Count - 1)`) but it just removes the literal last character.

I've also tried using `Replace(vbCrLf, "")` and many variations of it but again, they only remove literal new lines created in the string, not the new line at the end that is magically created.

Preferably, I'm seeking a method which will be able to remove that magical newline before the string is ever written to the file. I found methods which read from the file and then write back to it which would require Write > Read > Write, but in all cases the magical new line still appeared. :(

If it's important to note: The file will contain a string which may contain actual new lines (it's 'Song Artist - Song Title', though can contain other information and new lines can be added if the user wishes). That text file is then read by other applications (such as mIRC etc) of which output the contents by various means depending on application.

Eg. If an application were to read it and output it into a textbox.. the new line will additionally output to that textbox.. which is a problem! I have no control of the applications which will read the file as input considering it's the client which decides the application, so the removal of the new line needs to be done when outputted.

Help is appreciated~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Write` method instead of `WriteLine`.  The `WriteLine` method is the one adding a blank 0 length line to the file because it is terminating the `"Hello World"` string with a newline.

```
writeString.Write("Hello World")
```